# Join splitted JSON-LD data?

Tags: javascript, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

On an ecommerce website, we output JSON-LD data. The issue is, that we output our own product data (`name`, `sku`, `price`, etc.), and then an external service (Yotpo) outputs the rating data using JavaScript, that is hosted by Yotpo.

The issue with this is that Google seems to interpret this as two separate products:

Our data:

```
@type        Product
name         MyProduct
sku          MY-SKU
image        http://example.com/image.jpg
url          http://example.com/product
description  Lorem ipsum
offers  
    @type          Offer
    availability   http://schema.org/InStock
    price          749.00
    priceCurrency  NOK
manufacturer
    @type          Organization
    name           Foo Bar
```

Yotpo's data:

```
@type    Product
name     MyProduct
aggregateRating
    @type        AggregateRating
    ratingValue  4.5
    reviewCount  2
```

Are there any ways to 'join' these two without modifying the part Yotpo inserts?

Comment: You can’t modify anything in Yotpo’s part, i.e., not even adding a property, correct? If you can’t, I guess the only way would be to inject your own data via JavaScript within Yotpo’s `script` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by turning off Yotpo's javascript-injected snippet, but still having the rich snippets option on (you need to keep the option on to be able to fetch the data, disabling only the javascript-injected snippet is only doable by contacting their support), and then fetching the data via their API and inserting it into our own data